# Viewstate set Property value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use viewstate in application where I have found that encapsulating viewstate in property is much more convenient.

Here is the code what I do in my code.

```
 public List<TransactionEntity> TransactionData
    {
        get
        {
          if(ViewState["TransactionData"] == null)
                return new List<TransactionEntity>();
          return _TransactionData as List<TransactionEntity>();
        }
        set
        {
          How to set value to gridview from here ??                
        }
    }
```

Now i have a gridview in user control which I need to bind everytime I assign value to this property.

Anyone knows how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i have a gridview in user control which I need to bind everytime I
>   assign value to this property.
>
> Anyone knows how to do it

```
 set
    {
       ViewState["TransactionData"] = value;
       gridview.DataSource = value as List<TransactionEntity>; //check if null etc 
       gridview.DataBind();// ...               
    }
```

Comment: It's worked although I have to call   grid.DataBind();

Comment: What do you mean _although I have to call..._ - of course you must call it. that's why I've written it.